# Mutate one column by filtering others in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset with several columns that are mutually exclusive. One of the columns contains the answer for that observation (e.g. "abc") while the rest of columns contains negative numbers that represent NA. As column A in the toy dataset below, a column always contains the same answer .

I want to create a new variable by merging the column with the answer for each observation. So far, I did it as below, but in the real dataset there are 50 columns for 2000 observations, so I'm looking for a more optimized (and more elegant) way to do it.

```
data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~A, ~B, ~C,
  "a", "ES01", "-1", "-2",
  "b", "-1","-3", "CH041",
  "c", "-2", "DDE24", "-1",
  "d", "ES01", "-3", "-1"
)

data %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(across(A:C, ~ ifelse(str_starts(.,"-"), "", .))) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(regions = paste0(A, B, C))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `unite` from `tidyr` and then remove the numeric/- characters with `str_remove_all`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
  unite(regions, A:C, remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(regions = str_remove_all(regions, "[^a-z]+"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  id    regions A     B     C    
  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     abc     abc   -1    -2   
2 b     def     -1    -3    def  
3 c     ghi     -2    ghi   -1   
4 d     abc     abc   -3    -1
```

---

Using the updated dataset

```
data %>%
   unite(regions, A:C, remove = FALSE) %>% 
   mutate(regions = str_remove_all(regions, "_?-[0-9]+_?"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  id    regions A     B     C    
  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     ES01    ES01  -1    -2   
2 b     CH041   -1    -3    CH041
3 c     DDE24   -2    DDE24 -1   
4 d     ES01    ES01  -3    -1
```

Comment: It works fine with the example, but in my real dataset the columns contains letters and numbers because they are regions. For instance, CH04, ES23, sometimes three letters and two numbers others two letters and three numbers. I'm trying to figure it out how to adapt the regex.

Comment: @JosepPueyo in that case, the `unite` step may cause confusion or else have to create a `sep`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try. Now, I edited the question to reflect this inconvenience.

Comment: @JosepPueyo do you have any other patterns

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I found an alternative approach based on @Cettt. Using `sep=""` in unite() and "-\\d" in the regex of str_remove_all()

Comment: @JosepPueyo We have to assume that the numbers in columns are always negative

Comment: Yes, they are. It's a code for different types of missing values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tidyr::pivot_longer` to transform your data into long format and then use `filter` afterwards:

```
data %>%
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "col", values_to = "answer") %>%
  filter(!grepl("\\d", answer))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  id    col   answer
  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 a     A     abc   
2 b     C     def   
3 c     B     ghi   
4 d     A     abc
```